# How can I count errors inside Excel VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code in Excel VBA to lookup PDF files and I cannot figure out a way to count the number of errors made by the research. Can anyone help me?

```
Sub Busqueda_MSDS()
    Windows("Excel1.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet 2").Visible = True
     
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim folder As String
    Dim file As String
    Dim route As String
    Dim format As String
    Dim errors As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    
    i = 2
    CARPETA = "C:\Users\documents\pdfs\"
    FORMATO = ".pdf"
 
    Do While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("G" & i) <> ""
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("G" & i) > "" Then ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Folder & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("G" & i) & Format
    
        i = i + 1
        errores = errores + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

The code itself already works, I just need to count the times when it fails.

Comment: You probably want to use `Dir` to test if a file with the specific filepath exists.

Comment: You received two answers... None of them could solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please, use the next adapted code:

```
Sub Busqueda_MSDS()
 Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
 Dim folder As String, FORMATO As String, i As Long, strErr As String, arrErr

 Set wb = ThisWorkbook
 Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
 folder = "C:\Users\documents\pdfs\"
 FORMATO = ".pdf"

 i = 2
 Do While ws.Range("G" & i).Value <> ""
    On Error Resume Next
     wb.FollowHyperlink folder & ws.Range("G" & i).Value & FORMATO
     If err.Number <> 0 Then
        err.Clear
        strErr = strErr & ws.Range("G" & i).Value & "|"
     End If
    On Error GoTo 0
   i = i + 1
 Loop
 If strErr <> "" Then
    strErr = left(strErr, Len(strErr) - 1) 'eliminate the last "|"
    arrErr = Split(strErr, "|")
    MsgBox UBound(arrErr) + 1 & " errors occurs..." & vbCrLf & _
               "The next pdf files could not be open:" & vbCrLf & _
               Join(arrErr, vbCrLf)
 Else
    MsgBox "No eny error appeared..."
 End If
End Sub
```

It will also return a list of the problematic files name (without "pdf" extension. Not complicated to add it).

Please, test it and send some feedback

Comment: Thank you so much! it was exactly what i needed.

Comment: @SANTIAGO PARRA MARTINEZ Glad I could help! But we here, when somebody answer your question in a convenient way, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accetped answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code in discussion works as it should. **I am not suggesting to do it for my code**... You received two answers, so please mark the on looking more convenient to you.

Answer (score 0):

### Count Missing Files

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CountMissingFiles()
    Const ProcTitle As String = "Count Missing Files"

    Const sFolderPath As String = "C:\Users\documents\pdfs\"
    Const sFileExtension As String = ".pdf"

    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range("G2")
    Dim dlCell As Range: Set dlCell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range(dfCell, dlCell)
    'drg.Interior.Color = xlNone
    
    Dim dCell As Range
    Dim sFilePath As String
    Dim MissingCount As Long
    
    For Each dCell In drg.Cells
        sFilePath = sFolderPath & CStr(dCell.Value) & sFileExtension
        If Len(Dir(sFilePath)) = 0 Then
            MissingCount = MissingCount + 1
            ' Highlight missing cell
            'dCell.Interior.Color = 14083324
            ' Print not existing filepath to the Immediate window (Ctrl+G)
            'Debug.Print "(" & MissingCount & ") " & sFilePath
        End If
    Next dCell
    
    MsgBox "Found '" & MissingCount & " missing files.", _
        vbInformation, ProcTitle
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank yo so much! it really helped me